# Can't expose port of local image with Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I have a PHP Laravel project, I have `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

COPY . /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    unzip

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
RUN php composer.phar update

EXPOSE 8000
CMD [ "php", "artisan", "serve", "--host", "0.0.0.0" ]
```

I build the image with `docker build -t laravel-app .` and run it with `docker run -d -p 8000:8000 --name backend app`, on http://localhost:8000 I can access the api correctly.

---

## The issue:

I am trying to use Kubernetes for this project, I've written a `laravel-deployment.yaml` file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend-laravel
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend-laravel
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: laravel-app
        image: laravel-app
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
```

When I try to deploy it `kubectl apply -f laravel-deployment.yaml`, the deployment is successful and the pod is created, but I can't access with http://localhost:8000
What I previously did:

- I've set docker to point to minikube with `eval $(minikube docker-env)`
- Create the service `kubectl expose -f laravel-deployment.yaml --port=8000 --target-port=8000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`...can't access with http://localhost:8000 What I previously did`

You can access http://localhost:8000 with `kubectl port-forward <backend-deployment-xxxx-xxxx> 8000:8000`. You can also expose as [NodePort or LoadBalancer](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/) where port-forward will not be required.

Comment: If I understand, I have to start minikube with some parameters like `minikube start --extra-config=apiserver.service-node-port-range=1-65535`